# FCM notification with topic server side not received on client

Tags: android, firebase, push-notification, firebase-cloud-messaging

I tried a sample code to test the push notification system with Firebase and it's working well except one thing.

- If I try to send a notification from Firebase console, using Device Token, the notification shows in device.
- If I try to send a notification from Firebase console, using my topic `topik`, all notifications show in all devices.
- If I try to send a notification from my web page or from [postman](https://www.getpostman.com/), using Device Token, the notification shows in device.
- If I try to send a notification from my web page or from [postman](https://www.getpostman.com/), using my topic `topik`, **NOTHING HAPPENS**.

This is a example call:

```
link: https://fcm.googleapis.com/fcm/send
POST method

Header field:
Content-Type : application/json
Authorization : key=MY_SERVER_KEY (the new one)

Body:
{
    "to": "/topics/topik",
    "data": {
        "title": "This is a Firebase Cloud Messaging Topic Message!",
        "content-text": "This is a Firebase Cloud Messaging Topic Message!"
    }
}
```

or

```
Body:
{
    "to": "/topics/topik",
    "data": {
        "message": "This is a Firebase Cloud Messaging Topic Message!"
    }
}
```

the result on send action is something like this

```
{
  "message_id": 7150560334538835864 (SUCCESS!)
}
```

but no notification arrives in any device. I tried to debug the `onReceive` method, but nothing happens.

Any idea?

Comment: Has your client device subscribed to that topic?  There's nothing in your question to suggest it has.  https://firebase.google.com/docs/cloud-messaging/android/topic-messaging

Comment: Yes. All clients are suscribed to that topic. Infact if I try to sand a notification from Firebase Console to that topic everything works fine.

Answer (score 1):

Are you trying to send data-messages or notification-messages?
see: https://firebase.google.com/docs/cloud-messaging/concept-options#notifications_and_data_messages

If you want to send notification-messages (the type of messages sent by the notification console)
the payload you wrote in the question is wrong. Try replacing `data` with `notification`:

```
Body:
{
    "to": "/topics/topik",
    "notification": {
        "title": "Hello",
        "body": "This is a Firebase Cloud Messaging Topic Message!"
    }
}
```